# SQL left outer join with n:m connection table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I want to have a left outer join with an n:m connection table between.

```
Table A 
   column: id_a

Table A:B
   column: id_a
   column: id_b

Table B
   column: id_b
```

Table b are holding all possible rows. So column B must be the left on.

I cannot figure out how to present to show all possible values for 1 Table A. I want to show all entires and the misssing ones ( that why left outer)

Using MySql

Sample data.

baskets (Table A)

```
 1 | basket x
 2 | basket y
```

fruit (Table B)

```
1 | apple
2 | strawberries
3 | grapes
4 | lemon
```

connection table

```
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 1
2 | 2
2 | 3
```

result
result for basket X query

```
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 3  (something which indicates it is not assigned . since there is no connection )
1 | 4  (something which indicates it is not assigned . since there is no connection )
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Can you show us sample data and your expected output?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What does the first column in your "result" represent? The ID of the basket? Or the ID of the fruit? Or something from the connection table? Sounds as if you want a full outer join by MySQL doesn't support that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a `cartesian` result. Consider the following sample,

```
declare @baskets table(basket_id int not null primary key identity, basketName varchar(255));
declare @fruits table(fruit_id int not null primary key identity, fruitName varchar(255));
declare @basketsFruits table(basket_id int not null, fruit_id int not null);

insert into @baskets(basketName)
    values('basket x'), ('basket y');

insert into @fruits(fruitName)
    values('apple'), ('strawberries'), ('grapes'), ('lemon');

insert into @basketsFruits(basket_id, fruit_id)
    values(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3);


select  b.*, f.fruitName
        , case when exists(select 1 from @basketsFruits as bf where bf.basket_id = b.basket_id and bf.fruit_id = f.fruit_id) then
            'Fruit Present'
        else
            'Fruit not Present'
        end as fruitStatus
from    @baskets as b, @fruits as f     -- cartesian all the fruits and all the baskets
where   b.basket_id = 1
```

**Results:**

[image: query results]